# Python - How to pass extra data to an inherited class

Tags: python-3.x

Being newer to Python, I am not sure how to pass my configuration data to a class, which inherits a Frame.

This read/sets configuration data

```
class clsConfig:

    # init method/constructor
    def __init__(self):
        path = str(sys.path[0]) 
        self.srcPath = path + "\\"
        self.imagePath = self.srcPath + "Images" + "\\"
        ................
```

This class has configuration data, creates a notebook/tab calling my inherited class

```
class maingui:
    def __init__(self):

        # Set Config Values
        config = clsConfig()
        config.getConfiguration()
    
        print("Config-Path: "+ config.srcPath)

        # root
        self.root = Tk() #Makes the window
        self.root.wm_title("My tab") 

        # tab control - Main Control
        self.tabMain = ttk.Notebook(self.root)

        # *** I WANT TO PASS config DATA HERE ***
        tabWeather = clsWeatherTab(self.tabMain)
        self.tabMain.add(tabWeather,text="Weather")
```

This class is where I want to have available the config class data

```
class clsWeatherTab(Frame):
   def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
       Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
       self.label = Label(self, text="Hi This is Tab1-seperated")
       self.label.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
       self.name = name
       
       # *** HERE I WANT TO USE PASSED config DATA ***
       print("Config-Path: "+ config.srcPath)
```

Any guidance would be great.

thank you,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is pass the config structure to the constructor for the tag frame:

```
class maingui:
    def __init__(self):

        # Set Config Values
        config = clsConfig()
        config.getConfiguration()
...
        tabWeather = clsWeatherTab(self.tabMain, config)
        self.tabMain.add(tabWeather,text="Weather")
...
class clsWeatherTab(Frame):
   def __init__(self,name,config,*args,**kwargs):
       Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
       self.config = config
       self.label = Label(self, text="Hi This is Tab1-seperated")
       self.label.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
       self.name = name
       
       print("Config-Path: "+ config.srcPath)
```